# What does it mean by error has a Gaussian Distribution?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, linear-model

Linear Regression assumes that the errors (εi) are random and independent, following a Gaussian distribution with mean of zero.

Equation is given by: $y_i = x_i + \epsilon_i$ , say i = 1...n

Does this mean each error($\epsilon_i$) has Gaussian distribution and the value of εi will any one value from the distribution (assuming the probability of course, the maximum probability of it being zero)?

Does it mean $\epsilon_i$ is a separate random variable?

Or do the collection of εi (from 1 to n) is from a single random variable (assuming a parent ε from where εi are taken) and that parent random variable has a Gaussian distribution?

I would appreciate any explanation. Thank you.

Comment: The simple linear regression problem also has a slope and an intercept. These are the parameters that you estimate. Gaussian distribution of error terms is only needed to justify MLE as optimal in the case of least squares. There is so much more that can be said about the assumptions and the properties of the estimates, The Gauss-Markov theorem is one example of things you should learn about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the assumption as if each $\epsilon_i$ comes from an independent Gaussian density with mean zero and variance $\sigma_i^2 > 0$. That is $\epsilon_i \sim N(0,\sigma_i^2)$, for $i = 1,\dots,n$.

But you can also look at it as if the random vector $\epsilon = [\epsilon_1 \dots \epsilon_n]^T$ is distributed according to a multivariate Gaussian distribution which has for mean the zero vector and for covariance matrix a diagonal matrix D where the diagonal elements of D are $\sigma_1^2, \sigma_2^2, \dots \sigma_n^2$. That is $\epsilon \sim MN(0,D)$.